# Strange behaviour of Android Studio after BSoD

Tags: import, android-studio, project, bsod

I was working on my android project in Android Studio ver 0.4.0. Suddenly I've got a BSoD (Windows 7 x86) and after rebooting and launching IDE it has become behave very unusual: all android.* and com.myproj.* imports became unused and all classes became unresolved. I've tried to sync project with gradle files but it hasn't affected. Maybe it's problem around project settings (.gradle or .iml files) but I have no idea what's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Android Studio 0.4.3. Those problems have been fixed in this version.